# Move the limits of \sum to right in displayed mode

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

I have an equation with a sum in it that is written in displayed mode. I would like the limits of my sum to appear on the right. However, when I write it, it appears with the limits below the sum. My code and its output are given below:

```
\[f(x) = \sum_{y\in X} g(x)
```

[image]

I'm sure there's an easy fix for this, but I'm at a dead end. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `\nolimits`, having this output?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\[f(x) = \sum\nolimits_{x\in X} g(x) \]
\end{document}
```

If your style dictates that all limits for big operators should go on the right, you can use the global option `nosumlimits`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nosumlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}

\[f(x) = \sum_{x\in X} g(x) \qquad \bigcup_{x\in X}A_x=A\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You were faster than me! (+1).Happy new year!

Comment: @Bernard I'm going to reciprocate now ahahah.

Comment: And, if the style requires this for *every* summation symbol, it's easier to call `\usepackage[nosumlimits]{amsmath}`

Comment: @egreg I'm not expert on this topic :-( It is the first time that I see this option....Please, can you edit my answer because the comment it is your. I wish you and all the user a BEST NEW YEAR and I hope also for me. I hope so much but my wishes never come true :-(